# hyphenation rule not acted upon

Tags: hyphenation

In this example, why is the hyphenation rule not used?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\hyphenation{abc-def-hij-klm-nop-qrs-tuv-wxyz}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabu} {|X|X|}
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz & 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 
\\
5 & 6 \\
\end{tabu}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your `\hyphenation{...}` is missing the letter `g`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. As Lev Bishop already said, the words are different, `g` is missing in the alphabet word in `\hyphenation`.
2. If the text width is decreased, the first word is not hyphenated because TeX does not hyphenate the first word in a paragraph. Adding `\hspace{0pt}` helps here:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tabu}
   \hyphenation{abc-def-ghij-klm-nop-qrs-tuv-wxyz}% g is added

   \setlength{\textwidth}{.5\textwidth}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{center}
   \begin{tabu} {|X|X|}
   \hspace{0pt}abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz &
   abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
   \\
   5 & 6 \\
   \end{tabu}
   \end{center}

   \end{document}
   ```

   > [image: Comparison hyphenation of first word]