# How does LaTeX make line-breaking for word that can not fit in cell?

Tags: tables, line-breaking, longtable

Often in my tables LaTeX doesn't want to line-break a word that can not fit in a cell.

How I can teach it to split such a word?

As you can see in my example below the same word in some cases will be split, in another cases not.

I want to teach LaTeX to split all words (that can not fit on the page) automatically.

Can you help me?

**Some example:**

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.1\textwidth} | p{0.3\textwidth}|} \hline
Text                       & Remarks   \\ \hline
new zoogeographical region &           \\ \hline
zoogeographical region     &           \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

[image]

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue seems to be that LaTeX doesn't hyphenate the first word in a paragraph. I don't know if there's a way to enable that globally, but in your case, adding `\hspace{0pt}` without a space afterwards solves the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.1\textwidth} | p{0.3\textwidth}|} \hline
Text                       & Remarks   \\ \hline
new zoogeographical region &           \\ \hline
\hspace{0pt}zoogeographical region     &           \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

---

To automate this process and apply `\hspace{0pt}` to every cell (in a column) to simplify automated table generation, you can use the `>{...}` syntax from the `array` package, which adds `...` to the beginning of every cell in the respective column. Here are the lines I had to change/add in comparison to the MWE above.

```
...
\usepackage{array}
...
\begin{longtable}{|>{\hspace{0pt}}p{0.1\textwidth} | p{0.3\textwidth}|} \hline
...
```

(The output looks the same.)

Comment: This seems to be a legit solution -- Heiko Oberdiek recommended it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67764/4012

Comment: I assume this is because the hspace now counts as the first "word" in the paragraph? I am looking at a similar situation, but I don't know beforehand what text is going to go in the table (Data generated through a script). Is there a way to globally change the hyphenation rule to include first words, or do so for the duration of a table? Throwing `\hspace{0pt}` in front of every single cell seems...ugly.

Comment: @Eric I agree, but I don't know. Sounds like a good question to ask here on tex.sx: How can I globally enable hyphenation for the first word in a paragraph?

Comment: @Eric You might not need this solution anymore, but I added a way of adding the `\hspace{0pt}` in front of every cell automatically.