# \hspace{0pt} doesn't make line-breaking for word that can not fit in cell

Tags: tables

I add `\hspace{0pt}`, but this issue doesn't solve.

Are there any additional usage requirements `\hspace{0pt}`?

[image]

I am trying to write

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.1\textwidth} | p{0.3\textwidth}|}
\hspace{0pt}abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz &
\hspace{0pt}abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
\\
5 & 6 \\
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: adding hspace allows the first word to be considered for hyphenation, but it does not make non hyphenatable strings hyphenatable.

Comment: The question is asked several times on this site, one of these answers should help https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=hyphenate+long+strings

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which document class do you employ? When I compile your code snippet under the assumption that the `report` document class, LaTeX does manage to find a few hyphenation points. (The only substring that LaTeX can't seem to hyphenate is `jklmnopqrstu`.)

Comment: @Mico I guess the OP is not using USEnglish hyphenation patterns.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - I was (pleasantly, of course) surprised that LaTeX would find even 3 hyphenation points in `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` -- after `e`, `i`, and `u` -- if US-English hyphenation rules are in place.  FWIW, if `babel` is loaded with the option `british`, it finds three (different, of course) hyphenation points. And if `babel` is loaded with `ngerman`, the number of hyphenation points jumps to 6. (Who knew that German hyphenation rules are more permissive than their US- and UK-English counterparts?!) Sadly, if `babel` is loaded with `russian`, *no hyphenation points* are found.

Comment: You need to load babel with correct language in your document's preamble, and use real words that LaTeX will find in the loaded hyphenation table. Or you may help latex by adding `\-` at the places you want LaTeX to hyphenate. See what happens when you use the following string instead of you own: `abc\-def\-ghi\-jkl\-mno\-pqr\-stu\-vwx\-yz`

Comment: I employ:
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtext}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

Comment: I took this table on this site https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67762/hyphenation-rule-not-acted-upon/67764#67764

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much "Sadly, if babel is loaded with russian, no hyphenation points are found." - so sad. I employ \usepackage[russian]{babel} because I write in Russian and for rusian word found hyphenation points. I have problems with english words in my documents.

Comment: @ЗанинаСветлана - You report that you loaded `babel` with the language option `russian`. If you have some English-language words in your document, you should specify `english` as the second language option and use babel's method for switching back and forth between russian and english. (Aside, I continue to hope that you're not actually trying to find sensible hyphenation points in the string `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`...)

Comment: @Mico How do I do this? I use \usepackage[english,russian]{babel}. 
I tried to use environment: \begin{otherlanguage}{english}/end{english}.
I added an answer with the real table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real table in my document. I use

```
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtext}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{g0019}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{listings}
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1  

\begin{document}


\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\scshape}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[c]{|>{\hspace{0pt}}p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|p{0.081818\linewidth}|}
\caption{Зависимые параметры DT} 
\label{tab:118}  \\ 
\hline
\thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{ITF.LEV}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TRTUTBL, с}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TRTETBL, с}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TVTETBL, с}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TVTUTBL, с}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TVPCTBL, с}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{H1TBL}\textbf{, }\textbf{мор. миля}\textbf{2}\textbf{/c}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{DMODTBL, мор. миля}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TVPETBL, с}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TVVTT\_TBL, с}
}}\\ \hline 
\endfirsthead
\captionsetup{labelformat=continued}\caption{} \\
\hline
\thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{ITF.LEV}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TRTUTBL, с}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TRTETBL, с}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TVTETBL, с}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TVTUTBL, с}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TVPCTBL, с}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{H1TBL}\textbf{, }\textbf{мор. миля}\textbf{2}\textbf{/c}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{DMODTBL, мор. миля}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TVPETBL, с}
}} & \thead[c]{\parbox{0.081818\textwidth}{\textbf{TVVTT\_TBL, с}
}}\\ \hline 
\endhead
3
 & 15
 & 15
 & 15
 & 15
 & 35
 & .002
 & .20
 & 25
 & 15
\\ \hline 
4
 & 20
 & 20
 & 20
 & 20
 & 40
 & .00278
 & .35
 & 30
 & 18
\\ \hline 
5
 & 25
 & 25
 & 25
 & 25
 & 40
 & .00278
 & .55
 & 30
 & 20
\\ \hline 
6
 & 30
 & 30
 & 30
 & 30
 & 45
 & .00278
 & .80
 & 35
 & 22
\\ \hline 
7
 & 35
 & 35
 & 35
 & 35
 & 48
 & .004
 & 1.10
 & 40
 & 25
\\ \hline 
\end{longtable} 
\end{landscape} 

\end{document}
```

It looks like english is ignored. How to fix this?

[image]